# Need clarification on bit shifting

Tags: c

```
void test()
{

    unsigned char c;
    c = (~0)>>1 ;  
    printf("c is %u\n",c); 

}
```

It prints 255. I was expecting 127 as i was expecting the left most bit to be set to 0 after the right shift. Is this because my compiler is doing Right rotation?

Comment: Casting  it to unsigned char worked. Even for something like this. unsigned int x =  ~ ((unsigned int)(~0)>>1); you need to cast it to unsigned to get the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler is treating ~0 as an int, then shifting, then converting to unsigned char. This program outputs your expected value:

```
void test()
{
    unsigned char c;
    c = ((unsigned char)(~0)) >> 1 ;  
    printf("c is %u\n",c); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The literal `0` is of type `int`. Therefore the entire expression will be evaluated as type `int.`

The expression:

```
(~0) >> 1
```

evaluates as type `int`.

- Therefore `~0` is evaluating to `0xffffffff` (assuming 32-bit).
- After the shift it becomes: `0x7fffffff`.

When you store into `c` (which is `unsigned char`), it truncates to `0xff` which is `255`.

To get the `127` that you expected, you'll need to cast the `~0`:

```
c = (unsigned char)(~0) >> 1;
```

---

**Side Note:** Even if we cast just the `0` to `unsigned char`, the result will still be `255`. This is because of implicit integer promotion. All intermediates that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`.

More Info: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules

Comment: I don't see any promotion; `0` just inherently has type `int`.

Comment: Ha. Dunno how I overlooked that! I'll fix it when I get back in front of a computer.

Comment: @rocky Yes indeed. It might also be of interest to know that `(unsigned char)(~0)` will result in `0xff`. Then it gets promoted back to `int` as `0x000000ff`. Which ultimately returns `127`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `~0` is negative in twos complement (and sign-and-magnitude), and right shifting of negative integers is implementation-defined. A common behaviour of right-shifting signed integers is sign-extension, so in that case `(~0) >> 1` becomes `0xFFFFFFFF` (32-bit `int`s).